# Высота текста больше чем сам текст

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Высота текста больше чем он занимает на самом деле, в чём причина ?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header__text h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__text">
  <h1>Top designers</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вы указываете font-size 72 то это не значит что буквы будут высотой 72px

Comment: Так,  а как сделать чтобы не было этих отступов лишних, чтобы размер был по содержимому

Comment: Вроде никак я не очень вникаю в тему шрифтов предпочитая оставить все как есть:)

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так происходит потому что у шрифта есть область содержимого(контейнер), ее установил автор шрифта и вней отрисовуются элементы(знаки/буквы и тп).

У каждого шрифта есть свои метрики(размеры), размер контейнера вашего шрифта равен **1000em** (или UPM, units per em — единиц на кегль), а заглавные буквы равны **700**. Из за этого получается пространство вокруг элемента. Так же, стандартное значение `line-height: normal` может задавть доп. пространство, исходя из метрик для вашего шрифта оно будет равно

**Ascent(1000) + Descent(250) + Line Gap(0) = 1.25(1250)**

Что даст нам при `font-size: 100px` строку высотой в 125px. Но, сами буквы будут 70px - заглавные и 51 - строчные.

Что бы получить высоту заглавных в 72px нам нужно, желаемый размер разделить на высоту заглавных для вашего шрифта:
72 / 0.7 = ~103(`font-size: 103px`).

P.S. Данные расчеты исключительно для демонстрации. На практике скорее всего они вам не пригодяться, так как все шрифты имеют разные характеристики, их размер может зависеть от ОС и других факторов.

Более подробно описанно в [Неизведанные глубины CSS: метрики шрифта, line-height и vertical-align](http://css-live.ru/css/metriki-shrifta-line-height-vertical-align.html)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header__text .first {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header__text .second {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 103px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__text">
  <code>font-size: 100px;</code>
  <h1 class="first">Top designers</h1>
  <code>font-size: 103px;</code>
  <h1 class="second">Top designers</h1>
</div>
```